# django update_or_create method creates record but with empty values

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying use update_or_create method, it's working but the issue which I see is, it's creating an empty record even though the fields are null=False & blank=False.

Any idea about this folks?

Comment: what query are you using right now?

Answer (score 0):

If your field is `null=False` and `blank=False` that doesn't mean that the constraints are present in the database. Please check if the column in DB cannot be null and/or run migrations to add it to the DB.

Additionally you need to specify non-default values using the `defaults` argument of `get_or_create()`:

```
    obj, created = Person.objects.get_or_create(first_name='John', last_name='Lennon',
              defaults={'birthday': date(1940, 10, 9)})
```